# Big Oh - why is this inequality true?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am reading through Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual".

The first chapter states a formal definition for Big O notation:

`f(n) = O(g(n))` means that `c * g(n)` is an upper bound on `f(n)`.
i.e. there exists some constant `c` such that `f(n)` is always less than or equal to `c * g(n)` for large enough n. (i.e. `n >= n0` for some constant `n0`)

So that's fine and makes sense.

But then the author goes on to describe the Big O of a particular function: `3n^2 - 100n + 6`

He says that `O(3n^2 - 100n - 6)` is NOT equal to `O(n)`. And his reason is that for any `c` that I choose, `c * n` is always < `3n^2` when `n>c`. Which is true, but what about the `(-100n + 6)` part?

Let's say I choose `c = 1` and `n = 2`.
    `3n^2 - 100n + 6 = 12 - 200 + 6 = -182`

and `c * n` is `1*2` which is `2`. `-182` is definitely less than `2`, so why does Skiena ignore those terms?

Comment: Nobody really cares what the performance is like for a data set size of 2. Even bubble sort would be okay there :-) The idea is that efficient algorithms can _scale_ to large values of `N`.

Comment: @Damien, how should I interpret the phrase "for large enough n", is it just a question of choosing a constant c and then making n really large?

Comment: Having read Dukeling's answer, would anyone agree that maybe Skiena should change the phrase "for large enough n" to "for all values of n >= some constant"?

Comment: @patchwork: originally posted at the same time as you, but yes, that is the correct idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note the `n >= n0` in the definition.

If you pick some `c` and `n0`, it has to be true for **each** `n` >= `n0`, not just `n0`.

So if you have `c = 1` and `n0 = 2`, it also has to be true for `n = 1000` for example, which it isn't.

```
3n^2 - 100n + 6
=> 3(1000)^2 - 100(1000) + 6 = 3 000 000 - 100 000 + 6 = 2 900 006

c.n
=> 1(1000) = 1 000
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simplification. 3n^2 is greater than any 100n-6 for every `n >= (SQRT(2482)+50)/3 ~= 33.2732249428` - please check - it's simple equation. Thus O(3n^2) > O(100n-6). That's why it's not worth considering that part - it does not add any value.

Please note that according to definition you have to find (at least one) c for which every c*n is always < 3n^2 - 100n + 6 for every n greater or equal than some n0 (at least one). Just pick c = 1000 and n0=1000 and you will see that it is always true for those c and n0. Because I have found such c and n0 than statement O(n) < O(3n^2 - 100n - 6) holds true.

But I agree that this simplification might be misleading.